# How do the android actors get into costume?

Tags: costume, raised-by-wolves

The androids in *Raised By Wolves* are played by actors in skin tight costumes that look like they are made of latex or similar material.

They appear to have no zips or other fasteners, they are featureless.

How do they get in and out of those costumes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have a zipper in the back which they paint out (presumably with color-key paint i.e. green screen):

> What are the bathroom breaks like? I see you guys wearing a giant
> silver unitard. That can't be easy.
>
> SALIM: They definitely required quite a few hands in order to make it
> happen. One thing I don't understand, and I never will understand, is
> why they don't have a zip down there. You know what I mean? **It's like,
> they have a zip at the back.** Why don't they have a zip in the front?
>
> COLLIN: Imagine how many people that it would require **to paint that
> zip away** in a very uncomfortable area.[...]

Source [Amanda Collin and Abubakar Salim answer all our burning questions about playing robots on *Raised by Wolves*](https://ew.com/tv/raised-by-wolves-season-2-amanda-collin-abubakar-salim-interview/)